# Why my RegEx pattern in Unicode does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, unicode

```
import re
file = open('C:\item.bh.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-16')
pattern = re.findall(ur'[\u09ac][\u0995]', file)
```

It shows the following error:

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-22-bbd94837f9ee>", line 1
> pattern = re.findall(ur'[\u09ac][\u0995]', file)
>                                            ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: I am using python 3

Comment: @MaumitaBhaumik Since the answer below worked for you, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to have a raw unicode string here as you want the escape sequences to be interpreted. Second `re.findall` takes a string, not a file, so you have to read the file. The character classes are also not needed because they contain only a single character.

```
re.findall(u'\u09ac\u0995', file.read())
```

Or in context:

```
import re
file = open(r'C:\item.bh.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-16')
pattern = re.findall(u'\u09ac\u0995', file.read())
```

Comment: import re
file = open('C:\item.bh.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-16')
pattern = re.findall(u'\u09ac\u0995', file.read())         this syntax is also giving me an error

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 315564: truncated data

Comment: The above answer is for Python 2. For Python 3, just remove the starting `u` prefix.

Comment: Probably also double the backslash, or switch to a raw string for the path. It happens to work with `\i` but will break for `\n`, `\a`, etc.

Comment: The "truncated data" error should still reproduce unless you have changed the input file. It indicates that the file's contents are corrupted, or not actually UTf-16 (though that far into the file, probably the former).

Comment: "It doesn't make sense to have a raw unicode string here as you want the escape sequences to be interpreted".  Actually, Python regular expressions can interpret escape sequences so the string can be a raw string and still work fine.  Try it.